What is unclear about this question? It was closed without comment or down votes and the moderator keeps referring me to Meta

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: How can I determine the type of a tuple's elements directly from its type name in Swift?
What is unclear about this question? It was closed without comments or down-votes and the moderator keeps referring me to Meta for answers when I ask for a response. If the moderator closed it for some reason, shouldn't they be the one to answer why, especially when it is almost impossible for me to ask the question here on Meta?

"I had to use this comment to include any additional information." Not really, you were expected to [edit] the question to expand on your concern. I took the liberty of doing this for you, but please edit the question instead of continuing to post more information in the comments.

As far as I can see on that question, no moderators have interacted with you. Moderators are denoted by a diamond (♦) next to their name.

I'm not a swift expert, but I don't really see why your question would be unclear or need any additional information. Unless there is an inherent reasons why this questions wouldn't make any sense for swift, I think it should be reopened.

" shouldn't they be the one to answer why" - no anyone can and should do that. Providing feedback and curating content are two completely isolated processes. Unfortunately, feedback is anything but guaranteed nowadays for various documented reasons. A hard problem to solve.

@BDL I second this. @PipWasHere You could maybe try to short the question though. From my understanding, all you want is to see if there is a ArrayType.Element.type-equivalent for tuple's.

Just my impression, but the question looks good to me. I'm not a swift expert so I won't vote on it.

especially when it is almost impossible for me to ask the question here on Meta? - What does that mean? Why is it almost impossible? You obviously posted a question on Meta, so how is it almost impossible to do so?

@jps "participate in meta" is a 5 rep privilege is it not? If one perceives that they can't do anything positive, then it's fair to similarly perceive 5 rep as mostly unobtainable.

and the moderator keeps referring me to Meta for answers when I ask for a response. - It was a normal user whoch added the link to this discussion and this user was not one of the 3 close-voters. It's just a standard procedure to add a link to a Meta discussion, if there is any.

@Kevin But they posted here, so obviously it's not impossible. I think there an exception to the "5 rep minimum for posting on meta" privilege for posts about your own questions, right?!

@jps that link was added after this post was created. I don't know where the OP was referred to Meta, or by whom, but it wasn't on that question (unless it's a deleted comment). I suspect it might be on a deleted question.

@jps Low rep users can post on Meta by including a link to a post on the main site.

The answers that I do find are often out-of-date, not applicable to my needs, or never fully answered, if answered at all -- If you're capable of noticing that, you should also be capable of doing something about it in some cases.

@ThomA In this case, the interactions with moderators occurred via flags, which were declined with custom messages referring the user to meta.

It looks like you thought that moderators are the ones who close and reopen questions. In fact, most closing is done by regular users. I was one of the mods who declined your flag. Please don't ask mods for such issues as we often don't have the experience to reopen the question. It's also not something that is our job. Asking here how you have done is the right thing.

@Dharman Thanks for that info. I am still not clear on all the subtleties of this site, even using it as a resource for many years. I was not aware a question could be closed by another user. It was discouraging to a new poster like me. I do wonder who moderates those users who would close a question without comment.

Thanks, all, for the responses. Is there someway to mark this Meta question as "answered" or does it just remain as is for other users to peruse?

There's not a way to mark it answered, as such, since the answers ended up getting deleted.  You could leave it as-is, or delete it.  Up to you.

@PipWasHere ...a question could be closed by another user.... I do wonder who moderates those users who would close a question without comment... - It's usually not one user but 3 of them, and these 3 users have at least some experience on the site because close voting requires a minimum reputation of 3000. And there is no moderation, but at least 3 people have to agree on that matter and if you anyone disagrees, they can cast a reopen vote (as it happened in your case), which again requires 3 votes.

@RyanM wouldn't a self-answer give something to mark as answered?

Probably the biggest problem is that Stack Overflow isn't a forum :) It's closer to Wikipedia. That makes it harder to grasp as you can't really compare it to any other existing site and I assume most people won't be too familiar with how maintaining a wiki works, they just lookup existing articles and maybe make a donation. What you can really see in the wild is that people treat the site like Reddit, and apply tags like they would on social media and especially Twitter. All very wrong, but it's the habit that the internet has created.

I don't see the full history of the interaction, and I'm not a Swift programmer, but here is my attempt at an explanation of your key question:

"What is unclear about this question?"

One lead is this comment by one of the close voters (Cristik):

"This looks like an XY problem. Can you give details how would you use this information? Some code snippets to exemplify this would help, even if they don't compile."

I'm not that person and I didn't vote to close but it would be good if you reply to their concrete question - they are trying to help you!
Having looked at the question, I agree that the question is in places unclear. Why is the generic solution not sufficient? What is the generic solution, could you show it? Then we know what you're trying to achieve.
Your code snippet is helpful but a little bit unclear to me as well (as a non-Swift programmer at least):
typealias NamedTuple = (/*someunknowntype*/, /*someotherunknowntype*/)

// Later in the code...
let tupleType = NamedTuple.self // repetitive, I know... but I know how to get its own type
let tupleElement0Type = // <-- How do I get this from the NamedTuple alias?

In particular, it's not clear to me why you include that line let tupleType = NamedTuple.self. I don't understand it even with the comment, which I don't fully understand either "repetitive, I know... but I know how to get its own type". How is it repetitive? It doesn't repeat anything as far as I can tell? Have you included that line to show that that's not what you're trying to get? Then state that.
It's great that you tried to create a minimal code example, but maybe you went a little too far with the minimal here.
Overall, it happens that people vote to close and don't give detailed reasons. That's frustrating, I agree, and it would be very nice if close voters justified what they found unclear - but unfortunately there are too many new questions and too few reviewers (unpaid volunteers by the way like almost all of us here) - so sometimes this happens.

I have read the comments, of which I was a little unaware since I used to only look at Questions and Answers and skip the Comments. I will be more attentive in the future. You address my concern as did the others who commented. I agree it is an XY problem and I now know what I must avoid when posting new or editing this old question. Thanks!
